# Is there a way to add an attribute to a netcdf group in matlab?

Tags: matlab, variables, attributes, netcdf

In matlab is there a way to add an attribute to a netcdf group?

So far I've tried using the `putAtt` function and putting a `groupid` in the place of a `varid` but this caused errors.. Has anyone got any other ideas?

```
    netcdf.putAtt(ncid,groupid,'Date','18/09/2014')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve it if anyone's interested...

I replaced the netcdf id with the group id then replaced the second input with the global id which turns out is the same for all groups and netcdfs!

```
    groupid = netcdf.defGrp(ncid,'Group2')
    varid = netcdf.getConstant('GLOBAL');
    netcdf.putAtt(groupid,varid,'Date','18/09/2014')
```

Comment: If you have a newer version, http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ncwriteatt.html ncwriteatt might be easier to use.